# html/css button transparent second layer hover effect

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I want to implement a button. It is like this when it's not hovered:
[image: Unovered button]

the transparent rounded-bourder rectangle in the right is supposed to move left and cover the entire button in 1 second, when hovered. so, after hover, we'll have something like this:

[image: After hover]

My problem is that I don't know what to do. I found some code on the internet but either it comes from left to right or it pushes my arrow icon and text out of my button! I don't want my arrow icon or text change at all. I just want that the vright transparent rectangle move to right upon hover and then come back to it's original place.
My css code for my button withoug effect is this:

```
.btn {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    Border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 80%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fb815e;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Vazir', sans-serif;
}
```

update:
The effect should also reverse with the same speed when there's no hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want one element to be relative (wrapper) and the button / stretching part to be absolute. That way it will act as an overlay. You'll be relying on the transition for the one second, and width for the covering part.

This is, as far as I can tell, the exact button you want.

Edit: You asked for it to return, that's done by a second transition. One in the hover and a second one in the regular non-hover tag itself.

[image]

Disclaimer: I have no idea what the (Arabic?) text I used says.

```css
.btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fb815e;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Vazir', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;  
}

.btn:hover .btn-inside {
width: 100%;
transition: width 1s ease;
}

.btn-inside {
opacity: 0.5;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #fc9c81;
width: 20%;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
transition: width 1s ease;
}

.text {
margin: auto;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
    <span class="text">العاشر ليونيكود</span>
    <span class="btn-inside">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Hello. For the first part, it worked. But when you exit the hover mode, it comes back instantly, not with the same speed. How can I also fix that? I'm sorry I thought I have mentioned that it should come back with the same effect and speed.

Comment: @m0ss added it :) (explanation is in the Edit: part of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
className:hover{
//do stuff here
}
```

and then play around with opacity or whatever you wish to :)

Comment: Thanks. But the issue was with the moving part. The transition to be exact.